# Zurb Foundation template resize issue

Tags: css, resize, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I am building a personal site using a Zurb Foundation template (blog) and I have a resize issue. Basically, I wanted to make it responsive but I guess I messed it up along the way. I placed the footer in a larger container, and on resize it's not positioned where it should.

If anyone could help me keep it down, I would be grateful.

Here it is:

http://arbal.netii.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the `height:100%` values seem to be the problem. You may need to override them in a media query so they are reset to default on mobile.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Any hint on how could I achieve that? (never used media queries).

Comment: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries Here is a tutorial. You can also look at the CSS in Foundation, it has several media queries. Specifically these http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/media-queries.php